# preg_match with expressions

Tags: php, preg-match, expression

I have two types of lines that are being pulled from RSS. Those are the games being played and the games that haven't started. The code I have below only pulls the games that have started.

```
$string = "Tampa Bay 6 Florida 5 (FINAL - OT)
Ottawa 0 Toronto 3 (FINAL)
NY Islanders at Ottawa (7:30 PM ET)
Toronto at Tampa Bay (7:30 PM ET)
San Jose at St. Louis (8:00 PM ET)
Detroit at Nashville (8:00 PM ET)
Vancouver at Chicago (8:30 PM ET)
Los Angeles at Edmonton (10:00 PM ET)";

preg_match_all("/^(\D+)(\d+ )(\D+)(\d+ )\s*\((.*)\)$/m", $string, $result);

echo "<pre>";

print_r($result);
```

The important thing is that the teams remain in the same array for both types of lines. I have no idea what to do. Any help? I'm sure its just an expression I'm forgetting.

Comment: can you please tell what you need to extract from your string ?

Comment: Yes, please explain exactly what you want from `$result`

Comment: Does 'at' mean like "versus" and is a delimiter for the two team names?

Comment: yes that data is loaded from a feed so I can't change it. At is just there for home away purposes. The 'at' screws everything up so It will not load in those arrays. there has to be away but I have nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phew. Here's what I came up with. It uses conditional patterns to match the scores if there are any, and it will sneakily "remove" the the 'at' if no scores are found (indicating it is an unstarted match). It will use the same technique for the second team's score. lastly it will match the contents of the last paranthesis group.

Captured groups:

1. Team 1 name
2. Team 1 score (empty if 'at')
3. Team 2 name
4. Team 2 score (empty if 'at')
5. Contents of last paranthesis

   preg_match_all( '#^([a-zA-Z ]+)(?(?=\d+)(\d+)\s+|\s+at\s+)([a-zA-Z ]+)(?(?=\d+)(\d+))\s+(([^)]+))#m', $str, $matches );

   // note to edit-happy users, the regex cannot be formatted properly on SO.

**The only catch is that you should trim the team name's as there might unwanted be whitespace in them.**

### Breakdown

- ([a-zA-Z ]+) - matches the first team name
- (?(?=\d+)(\d+)\s+|\s+at\s+) - uses a [conditional check](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php) along with a [look-ahead assertion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) to see if a digit is found, if yes then capture team 1's score otherwise we match but DON'T capture the at string (ninja skills:)).
- ([a-zA-Z ]+) - matches the second team name
- (?(?=\d+)(\d+)) - another conditional check for the second team's score
- \s+ - match some whitespace before the remaining paranthesis bit
- (([^)]+)) - match everything inside the paranthesis

Comment: Thanks for the reply I get this `Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: assertion expected after (?( at offset 15 in /home/pspkr3w/public_html/test2.php on line 53` from this preg_match `preg_match("/([a-zA-Z ]+)(?(\d+)(\d+)|\s+at\s+)([a-zA-Z ]+)(?(\d+)(\d+))\s+\(([^\)]+)\)$/m", $resultsnba[$sportnba][$pnba], $resultnba);`

Comment: Yes me too. It worked in my regex tool but not when I tested it in PHP. Looking into it. Btw, impossible to format that regex with PHP in SO lol :)

Comment: I used your updated code and the question mark still doesn't allow it

Comment: @ZacharyTylerWiggins I got it working now :) I'm going to break down the regular expression now.

Comment: okay I got it to work! Thanks! One last thing can i get rid of the parentheses at the end? shouldn't be a lot to fix

Comment: Cheers. What parantheses do you mean? They're not captured in the regex.

Comment: your right I missed copying over a set lol cheers! thanks for everything. your the man!